# Redirecting at Adding Item Added Item

Tags: development

I have read this article: http://www.sharepointkings.com/2008/06/redirection-from-event-handler.html , and i put this line in my code: `SPUtility.Redirect("Event.aspx", SPRedirectFlags.Trusted, HttpContext.Current);` But debuger show me that is no Context. It don't cnow what context it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer to your problem is in the same article: http://www.sharepointkings.com/2008/05/httpcontext-in-eventhandler.html. Save HttpContext to the field in the constructor of your event handler class.

```
public class MyEventHandler: SPItemEventReceiver 
{
    HttpContext current;
    public MyEventHandler()
    { 
        current = HttpContext.Current;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: But it vrite me that method schould have return type.

Comment: And MyEventHandler() is getting underline red.

Comment: MyEventHandler() is not a method, it is constructor. So, I think the problem is in incorrect syntax in your class.

Comment: So how I can it manage ?